# Grouping Tables in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a table that looks like this -

```
 Car           Model
 ----          ---------
 Chevy         Suburban
 Buick         Skyhawk
 Mercedes      C300
 Chevy         Impala
 Chevy         Traverse
 Mercedes      C300
 Buick         Enclave
 Chevy         Suburban
 Buick         Skyhawk
```

I want to sort this table so that it looks like this -

```
 Manufacturer         Model        Count
 -----------          -----        -----
 Chevy                Suburban     2
 Chevy                Impala       1
 Chevy                Traverse     1

 Buick                Skyhawk      2
 Buick                Enclave      1

 Mercedes             C300         2
```

Basically what needs to happen here is the Manufacturer needs to be sorted and then models from each manufacturer needs to be sorted in a descending order....
I tried several ways to do this with Pandas and nothing I tried worked....
Any thoughts ??

Comment: please reformat your sample data using markup

Comment: If df is the name of your dataframe. Then `df.groupby(["Manufacturer", "models"].count().reset_index()`

Comment: Yes this works but can I get a count as well??

Comment: Thanks for the help Serge!

Comment: XXavir - Your suggestions works to identify the models uniquely, but does nor sort the manufacturer not the model count...

Comment: The Manufacturer needs to be sorted in alphabetic order or some other criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the Manufacturer to be sorted by the amount of Models:

```py
out_df = df.rename(columns={"Car": "Manufacturer"}) \
    .groupby(["Manufacturer", "Model"]).agg(Count=("Model", "count")).reset_index() \
    .sort_values(by=["Manufacturer", "Count"], ascending=[True, False])
out_df["Count_per_Manufacturer"] = out_df.groupby("Manufacturer")["Count"].transform("sum")
out_df = out_df.sort_values(by=["Count_per_Manufacturer", "Count"], ascending=[False, False]) \
    .drop(columns=["Count_per_Manufacturer"])
```

If you want the Manufacturer to be sorted alphabetically:

```py
out_df = df.rename(columns={"Car": "Manufacturer"}) \
    .groupby(["Manufacturer", "Model"]).agg(Count=("Model", "count")).reset_index() \
    .sort_values(by=["Manufacturer", "Count"], ascending=[True, False])
```

Comment: The first implementation worked like a champ...Many thanks!!!